# algoritmo con JS para carrito de compra ir sumando los productos con su precio de envio y el iva

Tags: javascript, class, push, javascript-metodo

algoritmo con JS para carrito de compra ir sumando los productos con su precio de envio y el iva, pero el problema que tengo es que el console.log no arroja resultado, obviamente me faltan mas if dentro del while pero estoy probando por ahora, gracias! que podria estar mal?

```
class Producto{
    constructor(tipoEquipo, delivery, precio){
    this.tipoEquipo = tipoEquipo;
    this.delivery = delivery;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio); 
    }
    envio() {
        if(this.delivery == "one day"){
            return this.precio += 3
        }else if(this.delivery == "standard"){
            return this.precio += 1
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
        
    }
    sumarIva(){
       return this.precio *= 1.21
    }

}


const producto = []

producto.push(new Producto("mancuerna", "", 10))
producto.push(new Producto("discos", "", 15))
producto.push(new Producto("cajones", "", 20))
producto.push(new Producto("pelotas", "", 25))

let comprar = prompt("Desea comprar algo? ")
let product = new Producto(prompt("Ingresa el nombre del equipo que desea comprar: "))
this.delivery = prompt("Ingrese el tipo de envio standard o one day: ")

while (comprar != "Si") {
    if (product == "mancuerna" && product == "one day") {
      console.log("ud ha agregado al carrito" + Producto.tipoEquipo + "por un precio de: " + Producto.precio + "quedando con el envio:"
      + Producto.envio() + "y un total con iva includo de: " + Producto.sumarIva())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Victor, en principio, en el log, usas **Producto.tipoEquipo**, cuando deberías usar **product.tipoEquipo** que es la variable que se crea durante la compra, y como tu dices, faltan varios **if**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hay algunas cosas que están "mal". Vamos a poner a funcionar el programa, viendo los problemas más evidentes

```
envio() {
    if(this.delivery == "one day"){
        return this.precio += 3
    }else if(this.delivery == "standard"){
        return this.precio += 1
    }else{
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Acá tenemos un problema. Si bien va a funcionar en principio, es una función con "efectos secundarios". No siempre es indeseable, pero en este caso al estar dentro de una clase, yo debería llamar a .envio() de ese producto 10 veces y obtener siempre el mismo precio, sin embargo, al hacer return this.precio += x primero estoy modificando el precio, luego devolviendo su valor. Por lo cual, si consultase varias veces el precio de un mismo producto, cada vez me daría un valor más alto.
Lo cambiaría por algo así

```
getPrecioConEnvio() {
    if(this.delivery == "one day"){
        return this.precio + 3
    }else if(this.delivery == "standard"){
        return this.precio + 1
    }else{
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

Lo mismo con la siguiente función

```
sumarIva(){
   return this.precio *= 1.21
}
```

Modifica el precio original (sin impuestos). Conviene consultar el precio del envio y devolverlo con IVA cuando se consulta, así no modificamos el precio original

```
sumarIva(){
   return this.getPrecioConEnvio() * 1.21
}
```

Sigamos:

```
const producto = []

producto.push(new Producto("mancuerna", "", 10))
producto.push(new Producto("discos", "", 15))
producto.push(new Producto("cajones", "", 20))
producto.push(new Producto("pelotas", "", 25))
```

No tiene sentido guardar en un arreglo, sí para el carrito por ejemplo, pero es preferible para acceder mejor luego a los precios, guardar los mismos en un objeto

```
const precios = {
  "mancuerna": 10,
  "discos": 15,
  "cajones": 20,
  "pelotas": 25
}
```

Consultar el tipo de compra después de responder si desea comprar. Y el while asumo que sólo debería salir cuando contesta que no quiere comprar más.

```
let comprar = prompt("Desea comprar algo?")
while (comprar.toLowerCase() != "no") {
  let productName = prompt("Ingresa el nombre del equipo que desea comprar: ")
```

Para crear el producto, reutilizamos la lista de precios

```
let product = new Producto(productName, "", precios[productName])
```

Esto está mal

```
this.delivery = prompt("Ingrese el tipo de envio standard o one day: ")
```

pues this acá no se refiere al producto, sino al objeto Window de JS probablemente, lo cambiaría por:

```
let deliveryType = prompt("Ingrese el tipo de envio standard o one day: ")
product.delivery = deliveryType
```

Y luego aquí

```
if (product == "mancuerna" && product == "one day") {
  console.log("ud ha agregado al carrito" + Producto.tipoEquipo + "por un precio de: " + Producto.precio + "quedando con el envio:"
  + Producto.envio() + "y un total con iva includo de: " + Producto.sumarIva())
}
```

Haces referencia a Producto como clase, cuando en realidad debes referirte a la instancia product, del producto que has creado.

Quedaría algo así:

```js
class Producto{
    constructor(tipoEquipo, delivery, precio){
    this.tipoEquipo = tipoEquipo;
    this.delivery = delivery;
    this.precio = parseFloat(precio); 
    }
    getPrecioConEnvio() {
        if(this.delivery == "one day"){
            return this.precio + 3
        }else if(this.delivery == "standard"){
            return this.precio + 1
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sumarIva(){
       return this.getPrecioConEnvio() * 1.21
    }

}

const carrito = []

const precios = {
  "mancuerna": 10,
  "discos": 15,
  "cajones": 20,
  "pelotas": 25
}

let comprar = prompt("Desea comprar algo?")

while (comprar.toLowerCase() != "no") {
    let productName = prompt("Ingresa el nombre del equipo que desea comprar: ")
    let product = new Producto(productName, "", precios[productName])
    let deliveryType = prompt("Ingrese el tipo de envio standard o one day: ")
    product.delivery = deliveryType
    if (product.tipoEquipo == "mancuerna" && product.delivery == "one day") {
      console.log("ud ha agregado al carrito " + product.tipoEquipo + " por un precio de: " + product.precio + " quedando con el envio: "
      + product.getPrecioConEnvio() + " y un total con iva includo de: " + product.sumarIva())
    }
    carrito.push(product)
    comprar = prompt("Desea comprar algo más?")
}
```